# Saving Detected Objects Individually from Point Cloud with RANSAC and DBSCAN

Tags: numpy, point-clouds, dbscan, open3d, ransac

**Hello,
I am trying to detect objects from point cloud data using RANSAC and DBSCAN algorithms. I need to save these detected objects as separate files and then produce their solid models. But I was not able to save the objects. I'm new to python and I don't know much about what to do, if you can help I'd appreciate it.**

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time 
import pandas as pd
start = time.time()

 
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("D:\\Bitirme_Veri\\mini.pcd")
plane_model, inliers = pcd.segment_plane(distance_threshold=0.05, ransac_n=3, num_iterations=1000)
inlier_cloud = pcd.select_by_index(inliers)
outlier_cloud = pcd.select_by_index(inliers, invert=True)
inlier_cloud.paint_uniform_color([1, 0, 0])
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([inlier_cloud, outlier_cloud])
o3d.io.write_point_cloud("D:\\bitirme2\\Sonuçlar\\sonuc1.pcd", outlier_cloud, write_ascii=True, compressed=True, print_progress=False)
#DBSCAN
labels = np.array(outlier_cloud.cluster_dbscan(eps=0.05, min_points=5))
max_label = labels.max()
colors = plt.get_cmap("tab20")(labels / (max_label 
if max_label > 0 else 1))
colors[labels < 0] = 0

inlier_cloud.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors[:, :3])
colors = plt.get_cmap("tab10")(labels / (max_label if max_label > 0 else 1))
colors[labels < 0] = 0
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([outlier_cloud])
end = time.time()
print(f"süre: { end-start:.3f}")
o3d.io.write_point_cloud("D:\\bitirme2\\Sonuçlar\\Bolge2v3.pcd", outlier_cloud, write_ascii=True, compressed=True, print_progress=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with a PCD file I have. I was able to save the files and I can see that the saved files contain points.

I would suggest you check the followings:

1. See if the input point cloud has valid points (if the coordinates are `nan` or if there is any point at all). This can be checked by `print(np.asarray(pcd.points))`. You can use the same statement before saving point clouds also to see if the saved point cloud has any points.
2. Depending on your input, you might need to change the hyperparameters (the arguments of `segment_plane` and `cluster_dbscan`). For example, when I set `distance_threshold` to 5, `segment_plane` is not able to detect any plane from my input point cloud.

Comment: Hi Dilara, thank you for your reply. In the code, 2 separate print commands work for me as well.However, my goal is to save the objects detected by the algorithm in the final stage as separate point clouds. (For example, the first file is the table determined by the algorithm, the second file is the point cloud data of the wall.)

Comment: 1. wall: In order to save a planar surface detected by `segment_plane`, you should save `inlier_cloud` instead of `outlier_cloud`.   

2. table: Could you please clarify if you are specifically interested in points that belong to a table or any object that might exist in the scene. Because if it is the former case, then you would need semantic segmentation rather than clustering.

Comment: Actually I want to save the objects in the same cluster, I want to output the objects in the same cluster with the same label. The knowledge of what the object is, such as a table or chair, is not important. I hope I was able to explain.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification. Then I think your method seems legit. But I will have two remarks 1. You might want to try my second suggestion in the answer (changing the hyperparameters) as they affect the outcome significantly 2. Is your point cloud scene indoor? In my experience, I find obtaining good clustering results when I used DBSCAN for indoor scenes hard, possibly due to objects being close to each other. You might want to try different clustering algorithms (e.g., k-means) or semantic segmentation, even though you are not interested in what the objects are

Comment: Yes, point cloud data is indoors. Do you know how I can save these clusters one by one? I thought about printing with a for loop by selecting with select_by_index, but no results.

Comment: You can obtain the points that belong to label `a` by `obj_points = np.asarray(outlier_cloud.points)[labels==a]`. You can create a new point cloud that contains these points by `new_pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud(); new_pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(obj_points)`. Then you can save it using `write_point_cloud `

Comment: Thank you very much Dilara, as you mentioned, when I wrote with label numbers, I recorded the points with the same label one by one.

Comment: Hello again, do you have any idea how I can print all labels at once? There are labels between 0 and 36.